# Inject settings or load once-global lookup?

Tags: java, architecture, dependency-injection, guice, application-settings

Still getting the hang of good dependency injection techniques vs overkill. Thoughts appreciated.

I have an application that, when it starts up, reads settings from a file. It could be a database later, I've written the part that loads the settings in a dependency injection (Guice) way, that's not a problem. These settings don't change by normal use of the application, but in a future version I may want to allow the user to change these settings from a GUI.

Here's the actual question: how should I have the various parts of the code access these settings? Some of the settings are only important very deep in the object hierarchy, but the parent objects don't need to know about them. So I could:

1. Use a singleton, then lookup the appropriate settings in the constructor
2. Pass the different settings (or the entire settings class) down the object tree
3. Create factories that get loaded by the Guice module, then use `Factory.get()`

I'm not sure how much better #3 is than #1... or is there a better way entirely?

Note: while I am using Guice, this is more an architecture question than a "how do I use XXX framework" question. So don't be afraid to answer even if you don't know Guice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CDI you can annotate your Singleton class with "@Singleton" and just inject an object of this class into a subclass property.
Don't know how it is in Guice.
I think using a Injection mechanism to ensure only one Property instance is the best solution.
Hope I could help.

Comment: In other words, you recommend option 1?

Comment: Yes. That way you ensure there is only one Property object. Wonder what could happen if 2 users edit 2 different Property objects? "Global Properties" is a default example of Singleton because of this situation.